# Restrict CORS to specific domain in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cors, fetch

I would like to restrict my rails backend hosted on heroku to accept CORS requests only from my frontend.

This is my `cors.rb`:

```
  allow do
    origins 'https://seanhetzel.github.io/adventure_archive_frontend'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

However, when I provide the frontend domain, it is blocked and throws this error:

`index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://dry-sands-78217.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sites' from origin 'https://seanhetzel.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I've looked at https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/wiki/Origins-examples for documentation.

Am I not providing the domain in the correct format? Is there something wrong with the fetch request?

Comment: Change your server config to `origins 'https://seanhetzel.github.io'` — because
`https://seanhetzel.github.io/adventure_archive_frontend` isn’t an origin. Origin values can’t have a path component — not even a `/` trailing slash.

Comment: @sideshowbarker that worked thanks! I guess that means there's no way to differentiate between projects if they're all hosted on github pages...

Comment: Yeah, the CORS protocol at least doesn’t provide a way to specify that you want the browser to allow requests from some apps within a particular origin but not from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your origin path is incorrect. An origin path needs to be an absolute URL path to the root directory of the website.

So replace :

```
origins 'https://seanhetzel.github.io/adventure_archive_frontend'
```

with :

```
origins 'https://seanhetzel.github.io'
```